# Set background image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: 'url(this.state.image)'}}>Hello World!</div>
```

This is my code. And it doesnt work. I am trying to set the background based on what props is sent to the component.

Comment: You are missing a closing brakets `}` in the style before Hello world. 
<div style={{backgroundImage: 'url(this.state.image)'}}>Hello World!</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use template string instead of plain string:

```
style = {{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.image})`}}
```

or

```
style = {{backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.state.image + ')'}}
```